# How to check English Grammatical relation ancestor?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I want to update a Java code that is actually using Stanford Parser 2.0.4 to a newer version (3.6)

The problem is that the function "EnglishGrammaticalRelations.SUBJECT.isAncestor" is not working in 3.6 and I need to check if a relation is equal to or an ancestor of another one. My code with Stanford 2.0.4 is as follows:

```
String sentence = "The company is a subsidiary of International Data Group";

    Tree depTree;
    SemanticGraph semanticGraph;
    LexicalizedParser lp;
    TokenizerFactory<CoreLabel> tokenizerFactory;
    LexicalizedParserQuery lpq;
    lp = LexicalizedParser
            .loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
    tokenizerFactory = PTBTokenizer.factory(new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "");

    lpq = lp.parserQuery();

    List<CoreLabel> tokenizedSentence = tokenizerFactory.getTokenizer(
            new StringReader(sentence)).tokenize();
    lpq.parse(tokenizedSentence);
    depTree = lpq.getBestParse();//getBestPCFGParse();
    // use uncollapsed dependencies to facilitate tree creation

    semanticGraph = SemanticGraphFactory.makeFromTree(depTree, false);

    System.out.println("compact graph" + semanticGraph.toCompactString());

    for (SemanticGraphEdge e : semanticGraph.edgeIterable()) {
        if (EnglishGrammaticalRelations.SUBJECT.isAncestor(e.getRelation())) {
            System.out.println("This is any subject");
        }

    }
```

And using Stanford 3.6 a few modifications were required:

```
String sentence = "The company is a subsidiary of International Data Group";

    Tree depTree;
    SemanticGraph semanticGraph;
    LexicalizedParser lp;
    TokenizerFactory<CoreLabel> tokenizerFactory;
    LexicalizedParserQuery lpq;
    lp = LexicalizedParser
            .loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
    tokenizerFactory = PTBTokenizer.factory(new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "");

    lpq = lp.lexicalizedParserQuery();

    List<CoreLabel> tokenizedSentence = tokenizerFactory.getTokenizer(
            new StringReader(sentence)).tokenize();
    lpq.parse(tokenizedSentence);
    depTree = lpq.getBestPCFGParse();//getBestParse();
    // use uncollapsed dependencies to facilitate tree creation

    semanticGraph = SemanticGraphFactory.makeFromTree(depTree, false);

    System.out.println("compact graph" + semanticGraph.toCompactString());

    for (SemanticGraphEdge e : semanticGraph.edgeIterable()) {
        if (EnglishGrammaticalRelations.SUBJECT.isAncestor(e.getRelation())) {
            System.out.println("This is any subject");
        }

    }
```

Could you please give me a correct example to use or test this new version?

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3.5.2, the default dependency representation in CoreNLP is the new [Universal Dependencies](http://www.universaldependencies.org) representation. As part of this change, the grammatical relations are now defined in the `UniversalEnglishGrammaticalRelations` class, and therefore you'll have to change your last if-statement as following:

```
for (SemanticGraphEdge e : semanticGraph.edgeIterable()) {
  if (UniversalEnglishGrammaticalRelations.SUBJECT.isAncestor(e.getRelation())) {
    System.out.println("This is any subject");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sebastian, is working fine. However, there are deprecated or extinct  functions  in my code (e.g. EnglishGrammaticalRelations.PREPOSITIONAL_COMPLEMENT) that I need to change or find a similar operation.

Comment: Yes, the treatment of prepositional phrases changed in UD and therefore there is no longer a `pcomp` relation. Take a look at these [migration guidelines](http://universaldependencies.org/docs/en/overview/migration-guidelines.html#treatment-of-prepositional-phrases) which explain the differences between Stanford Dependencies and Universal Dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look on the guidelines